# How to retrieve json key pair value of desc which is not json array?

Tags: android, json

```
for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {   
  JSONObject item_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
  String nameval=item_data.getString("name");  
  String descrip=item_data.getString("desc");}
```

where desc

```
{"0":"No Pain","1":"Mild","2":"Medium","3":"high","4":"Severe","5":"Critical"}
```

how can i get  these values in string?

Comment: There is no "name" and "desc" attributes in your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to treat the desc element as a JSONObject:

```
JSONObject  desc = item_data.getJSONObject("desc");
String elem0 = desc.getString("0");
```